# PostgresSQL JPA custom sequence

Tags: jpa, sequence

1. in postgres I create sequence: user_details_userid_seq
2. now I want to use it in my class

```
public class UserDetails {
    @Id
    private int userId;
```

I want what userId would read and generate next value of user_details_userid_seq (which is defined in databas). How to do this?

Comment: `@GeneratedValue(strategy = SEQUENCE, generator = "user_details_generator") @SequenceGenerator(name = "user_details_generator", sequenceName="user_details_userid_seq", allocationSize = <your_sequence_increment>)`

Comment: Just keep in mind that `allocationSize = 1` might not be the most performant solution. However, if other apps can insert data into your table, it is also the least confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks [crizzis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64630592/postgressql-jpa-custom-sequence#comment114276667_64630592) for keywords to search, but solution:

```java
@GeneratedValue(generator="my_seq_gen")
@SequenceGenerator(name="my_seq_gen", sequenceName="user_details_userid_seq", allocationSize = 1)
```

where the parameter `allocationSize = 1` defines your *sequence-increment* as `1`.